# Несколько одновременных анимаций

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в вопросе.

На [страничке](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js2/test0/) в `.nav_top` реализовал меню как на apple.com . Проблема в том, что при клике по полю поиска анимация блока `.search_form` отстаёт по скорости от анимации блока `.nav_top ul`

Я понимаю процесс так: анимация происходит в `changeWidth()`. при каждом проходе цикла:

1. уменьшается на `1px` ширина каждого
      пункта меню(выстраивается очередь
      10ms * 8 = 80ms)
2. увеличивается на 8px ширина блока поиска(добавляется в очередь еще
      несколько ms)
3. очередь в данный момент свободна, начинается следующий проход цикла(п.
      1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем не стал до конца вникать в принцип работы вашего скрипта, но скажу так: явно видны лишние строки кода, в т.ч. и добавляемая анимация к полю в цикле?

Я немного исправил ваш код: http://jsfiddle.net/kynqp/

Но думаю, тут нужно всё заново переписать, так будет проще.

Я бы сделал так: http://jsfiddle.net/SY2uD/

Comment: второй вариант конечно лучше. спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin ну уж не знаю, всегда любил таблички, да и проблем с ними не было особо.